# Romper ciclos desde otra función en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero salir de una función desde otra función, de manera que:

```py
def funcion_break():
    print("Estas a punto de salir")
    # Aquí iría lo que sea que rompe la función

def funcion1():
    print("Esta es la funcion 1")
    if True:
        funcion_break()

    print("Si esto se ejecuta, es que algo va mal")
```

Sencillo, ¿no?. He probado con invocación de errores de manera que:

```py
def funcion_break():
    try:
        raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print("ERROR: Esto es un error")
```

He probado en vez de print, con un return, pero el mensaje no aparece y tampoco sirve.

En mi proyecto en específico, esta función se usará varias veces en diversos proyectos, ya que llamo a la función `launch_error(*args)` (que sería la equivalente a la `funcion_break()`), la cual coge tantas cadenas como quiera y las imprime en diferentes líneas en forma de error. El esquema que sigo para esto es lo que dije en el ejemplo de los errores. Esta función la importo desde el archivo errores.py con `from errores import launch_error` (Queda evidente que estan en la misma carpeta).

Lo que quiero conseguír es hacer lo que hacen los errores, pero de forma personalizada de manera que pare la ejecución del programa lanzando un mensaje por pantalla.

Siento mucho el ladrillo.¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias :-)

Comment: Entiendo que un `sys.exit()` no vale. ¿Podrías explicar qué problema quieres solucionar con esto? "Saltar" una función parece poco ortodoxo, lo mismo una distribución diferente de requisitos ayude a hacerlo de forma más intuitiva

Comment: Bueno, la verdad es que no he usado el sys.exit() ya que en mi proyecto no tengo las dos funciones en el mismo archivo, sino que importo la función de otro archivo en la misma carpeta y temo que el sys.exit() solo saldria de uno. Ahora edito mi pregunta con mi proyecto. Espero que ayude.

Comment: ¿Has pensado en hacer un `raise` específico, tipo `raise NoSeContrasenya()`? Luego `funcion1` recogería los tipos de raise y actuaría en función del caso. Y lo de `print("si esto se ejecuta...")` quedaría fuera de los casos conocidos contemplados.

Comment: Funcionaría perfectamente, pero lo que quiero evitar es la repetición de código una y otra vez, ya que si tengo que hacer eso, tendria que añadir minimo un error con su correspondiente `try` y `except` y es justo lo que quiero evitar. De todas maneras, es una muy buena solución y, si no hay otra manera, que no te quepa duda que voy a usarla, gracias :-)

Comment: Mmm no sé si me expliqué bien, me refiero a poner el `except` en funcion1, no en funcion_break

Comment: Eso está entendido, pero en mi programa hay muchas excepciones diferentes y aunque creara los diferentes errores en el archivo de los errores, tendría que repetir el esquema `try - except` en el archivo de funcion1 y es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106779/discussion-between-esteban-and-fedorqui-so-deja-de-danar).

Comment: Podrías poner un decorador a todas ellas. Puedo intentar montar una respuesta, pero sigo pensando que lo mismo una estructura diferente podría ser más práctica, no sé si podrías dar más detalles

Comment: Nada tio, ni te compliques. `sys.exit()`, aunque sea importado, funciona. Haz la solución si quieres, pero ponla a modo de respuesta a la pregunta, así te puedo dar algo de reputación, que te lo mereces XD. No, enserio pon la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como hablamos en los comentarios, probablemente lo más rápido sea poner un simple `sys.exit()` para que salga del programa:

```
import sys
def funcion_break():
    print("Estas a punto de salir")
```

---

Sin embargo, también podrías crear excepciones propias y ver si se entra o no con `try / except`:

```
class HaceSol(Exception):
    pass

class HayArcoiris(Exception):
    pass

class DiaAburrido(Exception):
    pass


def _funcion_break(num=None):
    print("Estas a punto de salir")
    if num == 1:
        raise HaceSol()
    elif num == 2:
        raise HayArcoiris()
    else:
        raise DiaAburrido()


def _funcion1():
    print("Esta es la funcion 1")
    try:
        _funcion_break()
    except HaceSol:
        print('mira qué bien')
    except HayArcoiris:
        print('suelta el unicornio')
    except DiaAburrido:
        print('vuelve a dormir')
    else:
        print("Si esto se ejecuta, es que algo va mal")
```

---

Comentas que hay distintas funciones que utilizarían este `funcion_break()`, de ahí que también podrías utilizar un decorador sobre todas ellas:

```
def handle_errors(function):
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
        func = function(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            _funcion_break(*args, **kwargs)
        except HaceSol:
            print('mira qué bien')
        except HayArcoiris:
            print('suelta el unicornio')
        except DiaAburrido:
            print('vuelve a dormir')
        else:
            print("Si esto se ejecuta, es que algo va mal")


    return wrapped_function

@handle_errors
def funcion1(num=None):
    print(f'parametros: {num}')

@handle_errors
def funcion2(num=None):
    print(f'parametros: {num}')
```

Si llamamos `funcion1(1)` por ejemplo nos devuelve:

```
parametros: 1
Estas a punto de salir
mira qué bien
```

Comment: Gracias, eres un crack XD